# wpf innershadow of path

Tags: c#, wpf

So how can i go about generating an inner shadow on my path. You can see in the example below i was able to create it on the border but im not sure how to get it onto my path. The goal is for the shadow to appear on the inner area of the heart.

[image]

```
<Border Background="LightGray" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Width="40" Height="20"
           BorderThickness="0" ClipToBounds="True">
            <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="-2">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="5"/>
                </Border.Effect>
            </Border>
        </Border>

        <Path Stretch="Uniform" Width="50" Fill="Red" StrokeThickness="5" Data="M74,130C40,102.4,0,69.4,0,40.3C0,17.1,15.3,0,40,0 c21.3,0,32.4,14,34,18.1C75.6,14,86.7,0,108,0c24.7,0,40,17.1,40,40.3C148,69.4,108,102.4,74,130z">
        </Path>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the shadow to be inside the line, so it fills the inner area of it or to fill the area its surrounding?

Comment: In GDI+ this would be a PathGradientBrush, but I'm not seeing a brush class for that in WPF.

Comment: There is a custom implementation with source code here: http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/02/Graphical-Paths-with-Gradient-Colors.html

Comment: to bad you can't just copy the shape and invert it so it reads the heart shape as being the negative part, then you could just do a dropshadow effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best way is try understanding about `ShaderEffect` - a kind of custom Effect which you can implement based on HLSL (High Level Shader Language). However doing so is not easy. Some simple effects can be done easily but to me  this effect is not so easy. You can try searching round such as for *glow effect in HLSL* - and try modifying it to make an inner shadow effect.

I would like to introduce a work-around here in which you use pure XAML. However we use the deprecated effect `OuterGlowBitmapEffect`, you can easily find a free library of `Effect` (which has the corresponding `OuterGlowEffect`) and use that instead of the `OuterGlowBitmapEffect` in the following code. The new `Effect` should be set for `Effect` property instead of `BitmapEffect` property.

Here is the code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="data" Figures="M74,130C40,102.4,0,69.4,0,40.3C0,17.1,15.3,0,40,0 c21.3,0,32.4,14,34,18.1C75.6,14,86.7,0,108,0c24.7,0,40,17.1,40,40.3C148,69.4,108,102.4,74,130z"/>
        <VisualBrush x:Key="heartGlow" Stretch="Uniform" ViewportUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox" Viewport="-0.25,-0.25,1.5,1.5">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Path Data="{StaticResource data}" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Path.BitmapEffect>
                        <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Gray" GlowSize="25" Opacity="1"/>
                    </Path.BitmapEffect>
                </Path>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>                
        </VisualBrush>
        <VisualBrush x:Key="heart" Stretch="Uniform">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Path Data="{StaticResource data}" Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Red">                        
                </Path>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Border Background="{StaticResource heart}" Width="50">
        <Border Background="{StaticResource heartGlow}"  OpacityMask="{StaticResource heart}">                
        </Border>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

You need to use the whole `Grid` above to render just what you want, it's some kind of composite element. The idea here is we use a glowed element (by `OuterGlowBitmapEffect`) to render on top of a normal element (rendering the exact original heart). The glow part has both 2 sides: inner glow and outer glow. The inner glow will cover the behind background and create the effect we want. However the outer glow should be cut off. We use `OpacityMask` to cut off that part and finally have a perfect result.

[image]